# View com parâmetros sem where externo?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

Preciso receber parâmetros para uma *view*, mas como ela tem o `COUNT(DISTINCT DTA_HOR)` não consigo com o `where` externo. Será que teria alguma outra forma?

```
SELECT EX1 ,EX2, EX3, EX4,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DTA_HOR) FROM TB_1
        WHERE EX1 = EX5 AND DTA_HOR >= '!!PARAM_DATA_INI!!!'
        AND DTA_HOR <= '!!PARAM_DATA_FIM!!!') AS FREQUENCIA 
FROM TB_2 
WHERE DTA >= '!!PARAM_DATA_INI!!!' AND DTA <= '!!PARAM_DATA_FIM!!!' AND LOCAL = '!!PARAM_LOCAL!!!'
```

Comment: Poderia nos informar qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados? E versão?

Comment: Olá Jose Diz , é o SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3)

Comment: O que você necessita é transformar o código que postou em uma _view_, sem cláusula WHERE, de modo que a restrição possa ser informada na chamada à _view_? // Precisa ser _view_ ou pode ser uma função do tipo _inline table-valued_? // Observou que, para um mesmo valor de EX1/EX5 o valor de FREQUENCIA será sempre o mesmo?

Answer (score 4):

> *Preciso receber parâmetros para uma view,*

Que me lembre não há como utilizar parâmetros para uma exibição (*view*). O que é possível é acrescentar, na chamada à exibição, cláusulas como WHERE e ORDER BY.

> *Será que teria alguma outra forma?*

Eis abordagem utilizando função. Não tive a oportunidade de testar os códigos sugeridos, mas espero que não existam erros.

**FUNÇÃO**
Para passar os valores como parâmetro, a sugestão é que utilize uma função do tipo *inline table-valued*.

```
-- código #1 v2
CREATE FUNCTION fnFreq (@dataIni datetime, @dataFim datetime, @local xxx)
     returns table 
return
SELECT EX1 ,EX2, EX3, EX4,
       (SELECT count(distinct DTA_HOR) 
          from TB_1 as T1
          where T2.EX1 = T1.EX5 
                and T1.DTA_HOR >= @dataIni
                and T1.DTA_HOR <= @dataFim) as FREQUENCIA
  from TB_2 as T2
  where T2.DTA >= @dataIni
        and T2.DTA <= @dataFim
        and T2.LOCAL = @local;
go
```

Como não foi informado o tipo de dado da coluna LOCAL, é necessário que *xxx* seja substituído pela informação correta.

Para chamar a função, uma forma é

```
-- código #2
SELECT EX1, EX2, EX3, EX4, FREQUENCIA
  from dbo.fnFreq (@PARAM_DATA_INI, @PARAM_DATA_FIM, @LOCAL) as F;
```

As variáveis a passar como parâmetro devem ser previamente declaradas e ter os valores assinalados.

---

Comment: Yesssss !!!! muito Obrigada :D