# Como criar uma View com filtro?

Tags: sql-server

Criei a seguinte query em meu BD, preciso criar uma View a partir dessa query, a mesma deve retornar as 3 colunas iniciais realizado, meta e acumulado, de acordo com que o select está realizando, porém no momento que eu estiver realizando um select na view eu devo passar um where informando o código do canal, essa parte eu não estou conseguindo criar, poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Consegue exemplificar melhor Gabriel, o que ela esta retornando na view e qual campo dentro da view você vai filtrar ?

Comment: @badCode hoje ela está retornando as colunas `A.REALIZADO, A.META e ACUMULADO` nessa mesma View eu preciso passar o campo `VEN.AD_CODCANAL`como parâmetro, esse campo retorna o canal no qual está sendo faturado, pois para inserir na minha aplicação essa seria a melhor forma.

Comment: Você precisa incluir no retorno da view esse VEN.AD_CODCANAL para poder filtrar, se não tem hoje vai ter que fazer o vinculo por join até encontrar o VEN.AD_CODCANAL e depois você vai filtrar com where (select * from minhaview where AD_CODCANAL = 'xxx') entendeu ?

Comment: @badCode aí que está o problema, no meu select ele já está sendo filtrado, ele é repetido três vezes como pode ver acima `AND   VEN1.AD_CODCANAL=1 `, `AND   VEN1.AD_CODCANAL=1 `, `AND   VEN1.AD_CODCANAL=1 `, ele traz o resultado do canal correto, porém quero poder filtrar fora da View, pois tenho mais de um canal para exibir, e não seria viável criar uma view por canal...

Comment: Então acho que deu ruim, pois não tem como passar parâmetro assim, a view é lugar para tu guardar o estado pronto do que tu precisa e aplicar a consulta em cima dos dados...

Comment: Você pode transformar a exibição (_view_) em uma função de usuário do tipo _inline table-valued_, que é de execução eficiente. Vide https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207629/view-com-par%c3%a2metros-sem-where-externo/

Comment: Para compreender como ocorre a expansão de uma exibição (_view_), vide https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224619/select-em-view-gera-sub-consulta/

Answer (score 3):

Uma `view` não aceita parâmetros como uma `function` ou `stored procedure`, então você não pode mudar o `where` de forma dinâmica.

Você pode filtrar o resultado de uma `view` a partir de um select se isso não for problema (muitos resultados por exemplo):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [dbo].[VWmarcas]
 WHERE  ...
```

Comment: Como eu faria nesse meu caso Ricardo? Pois vejo que mesmo assim não foi possível...

Comment: O ideal é colocar o mínimo possível de filtros do `where` da view, e ir filtrando no `select`, sua view pelo que vi está muito específica, para um mês/ano, ela deveria chara VWmarcasJul2018 por exemplo se for assim